# How to use filter function to return perticular data in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, filter

I have to return the email if the user_id from two different sources of data matches then it has to return the only email from the first source.
the first source is from the table results from PostgreSQL and the second source is from the JSON data.

I have tried this piece of code:

```
var table = db.query(select * from users); //it has 4 fields _id, name, email, phoneNumber
jsondata.map(function(item){
var value = table.rows.filter(function(x) {
    if(x._id === item.user_id) {
        return x.email
    }
});
```

});

JSON Data: I have added only 2 data here for example but I have more than 1000 data. that is item

```
{
    "_id": "5b56d462c53eb904fcb5a8fc",
    "user_id": 2,
    "date": "2017-08-29T08:22:00.000Z",
    "message": "jfgdshfgdfhgdshg"    
},
{
    "_id": "5b56d462c53eb904fcb5a8fc",
    "user_id": 44,
    "date": "2017-08-28T08:22:00.000Z",
    "message": "jfgdshfgdfhgdshg" 
}
```

Postgresql i.e x

```
_id | name | email       | phoneNumber|
---------------------------------------
 2  |  aa  |aa@gmail.com | 98998998   |
 3  |  bb  |bb@gmail.com | 09887665   |
 44 |  cc  |cc@gmail.com | 98765655   |
```

Comment: Whether the second source will be an array?

Comment: how does, JSON data from second source look like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do In this way

```
var value = table.rows.filter(x) {
     var mail=[];
    if( JSON.stringify(item.user_id)=== JSON.stringify(x._id)) {
        mail.push(x.email);
    }
 return mail;
});
```

Comment: `x._id.equals` is not a function

Comment: Can you add x and item both json data in post?

Answer (score 0):

I think both the sources are in the form of array. Please check the below method.

```
  var secondSource = [
    {
      "_id": "5b56d462c53eb904fcb5a8fc",
      "user_id": "1",
      "date": "2017-08-29T08:22:00.000Z",
      "message": "jfgdshfgdfhgdshg"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5b56d462c53eb904fcb5a8fc",
      "user_id": "2",
      "date": "2017-08-28T08:22:00.000Z",
      "message": "jfgdshfgdfhgdshg"
    }
  ];

  var firstSource = [{
      "_id": "1",
      "name": "xx",
      "email": "xxx@gmail.com",
      "phone": "xx"
    },
    {
      "_id": "3",
      "name": "xx",
      "email": "yyy@gmail.com",
      "phone": "xx"
    }
  ];

  // collect user ids from second source
  var userIds = secondSource.map(user => user.user_id);

  // Get filtered emails
  var filteredEmails = firstSource.filter(source => {
    if (userIds.indexOf(source._id) > -1) {
      return source.email
    }
  }).map(function(obj) {
    return obj.email;
  });

  console.log(filteredEmails); // ["xxx@gmail.com"]
```